# Drupal Profile 2 Dynamic fields

Tags: 7, commerce, users

I am working with Drupal Profile 2 . Based on User Input Yes/No . I would like to place the selection fields accordingly . 
Like If the experience Field if YES. I want to present Employer details Fields and if no . No Fields displayed.

Please suggest if this is possible or any modules available to do this.